# Show pencil cursor in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, cursor

I have a React JS application which shows a Content Table having multiple rows. A user can click on a row to open details & edit the content for that record.

Currently when a user hovers over a row, it shows normal cursor.

`cursor: pointer;`

Whereas we would like him to see a black pen/pencil cursor icon so that he can know that this record is editable.

I noticed that there is no such values for CSS property cursor. But I have seen those interactions on public websites.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another element in css to change what the cursor looks like if a class is editable.

```css
tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr.editable:hover {
  cursor: url('path/to/pen-cursor.png'), auto;
}
```

The tr class you would need to make sure IsEditable is 'editable'

```html
<tr className={isEditable ? 'editable' : ''}>
  {/* row content */}
</tr>
```